# max function on list do not work in scala?

Tags: scala

There is a snippet of scala code,which I think quite easy

```
val m1 = Map("age"->60,"name"->"x")
val m2 = Map("age"->99,"name"->"j")
val l = List(m1,m2)
val max = l.maxBy(_("age"))
```

However, instead of the expecting result 
    val m2 = Map("age"->99,"name"->"j")
I get an error:

```
<console>:13: error: No implicit Ordering defined for Any.
```

I know there is something wrong about the implicit parameter,but I don't know how to solve this problem.

**update**
further,suppose I need a more general solution for this,a function

```
def max(l:List[Map[String,Any]],key:String)
```

then 
max(l,"age") == Map("age"->99,"name"->"j")
max(l,"name") == Map("age"->60,"name"->"x")

Answer (score 4):

Your maps have type `Map[String, Any]` so compiler could not find `Ordering` for `Any` object. Add explicit conversion to `Int`:

```
val max = l.maxBy(_("age").asInstanceOf[Int])
```

Or try use `Map` with specific value's type such  as `Map[String, Int]` or similar.

Other way is to use `case classes` or `tuples`:

```
val list = List((60, "j"), (99, "x"))
list.maxBy(_._1)
```

Comment: type cast looks a bit "evil" in scala

Comment: @JadeTang: initial code is evil. You should use custom class instead of `Map`. For instance you could use anonymous class with duck typing: `val m1 = new { val age = 60; val name = "j" }; ...; l.maxBy( _.age ).name`

Answer (score 0):

Try Using last line as
`val max = l.maxBy(_("age").toString.toInt)`

Comment: You can't order by strings since `"11" > "2"`, you need to convert to an `Int` before doing the comparison.

Comment: @Lee -> Thanks i forgot to add that. :)

Answer (score 0):

This works,

```
l.maxBy(m => m("age").toString.toInt)
```

and is closer to intended semantics on maximal (numerical) age, even that it does not prove type-safe, the original maps type preserves no information on the intended types, as aforementioned.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work (not that I like the idea of `Map[String, Any]`):

```
def myOrder(k: String) = { 
  x: Map[String, Any] => 
    x(k) match { case i:Int => (i, "") 
                 case s:String => (0, s) } 
}

l.maxBy(myOrder("age")) // Map(age -> 99, name -> j)
l.maxBy(myOrder("name")) // Map(age -> 60, name -> x)
```

Comment: Map[String, Any] seems a bad idea,but I really need a map to store different types values.